# Background (cover) for iPad, iPhone

Tags: css, ipad

I came across several ways and questions about the sizes of the ipad and iphone and how to use different css. Is it really necessary, especially now with more versions of the ipad and iphone to have a different background for each and every device?

Almost every answer/site about this problem tells the user to use the resolution 1024 for an iPad but according to Apple's site the latest iPad has a resolution of 2048 x 1536 pixels?

So do I need to make one background with 1024 in width for iPad 2 (or whatever), then one with 2048 for iPad 3, another one for iPhone etc or is there an easier solution?
I thought "background-size: cover" would be the solution for every resolution (since it scales automatically) but it apparently isn't since it doesn't seem to work on an iPad.

Comment: I used this which worked on ipad and iphone: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ its a jquery solution

Comment: Ehm, wasn't a CSS pixel 2 device pixels on an iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So do I need to make one background with 1024 in width for iPad 2 (or
>   whatever), then one with 2048 for iPad 3, another one for iPhone etc

No. Despite the different device resolutions, they still follow the original numbers in terms of targeting them with CSS. So all iPads respond to `device-width: 1024px`, and iPhones still stick with `320px`, even if they now pack in far more pixels.

The only thing to be aware of is that iPhone5 is a little taller so it responds to 320 x 560px.

Anyhow, in terms of `background-size`, all of this is kind of irrelevant, because the whole point of it is that it can size the image appropriately to cover any screen if you use `background-size: cover`.

Comment: Yes it does. Do you have a test case where it appears to be failing? Or are you using an old iPad?

Comment: @ralphm I'm testing on browserstack. Correction: If you try `cover` for an element and not the html pages's background it takes the whole screens width and height as opposed to the elements width and height.

Comment: Hm, that's not what I've found. Feel free to post a Fiddle or CodePen example that we could test out.